# Crystal Report Missing few values of a field from database

Tags: vb.net

This is Wayne.
I have come across a problem and hope someone will be able to help, the problem is I have a table 'Events' with fields S_No, Name_of_Participants, Event_Code and School_Code. When I create a report with all the fields, I get data correctly in three fields but not in one field i.e 'Name_of_Participant' field. The value in this field is not being displayed properly, like first one is being displayed then next 12 or 13 not displaying, then one name will display and next 12 or 13 will not display, and this field has data when I execute the query in database.
If anyone has any solution for this problem please let me know

When I try to display the field data in combobox or listbox or a multiline textbox, the data is displayed properly but when I try to get the data from combobox or listbox or multiline textbox and display it in the crystal report the value doesnt display properly.
I am uploading the pictures for your references.

[Preview of 1st page in crystal report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rKJr.jpg)

[Preview of 2nd page in crystal report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xyK1.jpg)

[sql server data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtYIJ.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the "missing" data is due to a newline and/or Carriage Return characters preceding the text.
To confirm this, please right-click the Name field in Crystal, select ***Format Field...***, go to ***Common*** tab, and turn on the ***Can Grow*** option.

If that was indeed the issue, use a formula to replace CR and/or LF characters with "".